# Running ReactJs with SpringBoot. Reload page error WhiteLabel 404

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-router, http-status-code-404

When running a react app with spring boot and reloading the page, it gives a whitelabel error.

I ran npm rum build and copied the content to the resources / static folder. After build and run the spring application it is normally loaded localhost: 8080, but when it reloads the page it returns the error

*Whitelabel Error Page*
*This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.*

*Mon Jun 15 20:23:56 BRT 2020*
*There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).*
*No message available*

I just created the application in spring and copied the build folder from react to spring's resource / static. How should I proceed?

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution that worked for me: switch to HashRouting instead of BrowserRouting.

Comment: Take a look again at [answer] to see what's expected of a complete answer